# Mobiscroll with Wheels Option breaks using display:inline

Tags: mobiscroll

just found this plugin and like it pretty well so far. But, I'm having trouble with it. When I'm using the wheels option, I'm having trouble with the display:inline option working properly. If I remove the display:inline option and let it default to showing the input, I can click on it and it brings up everything in a modal fashion and it scrolls properly. Using the inline option, the scrollers won't work properly. Hoping someone can offer some assistance. Thanks!
Here's my code:

```
   var options = [{
        'Wheel 1': {
            Option1: 'Option1'
                , Option2: 'Option2'
                , Option3: 'Option3'
                , Option4: 'Option4'
                , Option5: 'Option5'
                , Option6: 'Option6'
                , Option7: 'Option7'
        }
            , 'Wheel 2': {
                Option1: 'Option1'
                , Option2: 'Option2'
                , Option3: 'Option3'
                , Option4: 'Option4'
            }
            , 'Wheel 3': {
                Option1: 'Option1'
                , Option2: 'Option2'
                , Option3: 'Option3'
            }
    }];

    $('#ProjectSpinner').scroller({
       theme: 'default',
       preset: 'select',
       rows:3,
       //display: 'inline' <-- This is what kills it,
       mode: 'scroller',
       showLabel: true,
       headerText: '<p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;">Automagically Spin Up Your Project</p>',
       wheels: options,
       onShow: function (html, instance) {
           $("input[id$='_dummy']").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: which version of the mobiscroll are you using and on which browser?

Comment: I downloaded the latest stable version yesterday ans had the same results on Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the select preset with custom wheels. You should not use both, at the same time. You either use the select preset without the wheels option, or you use custom wheels without the preset option.